# Autodividers in listview in JQM using filter

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am using autodividers in listview in JQM and populating new "pages" which works fine when all the list is displayed but when user filters the list, the corresponding page does not display. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious so would appreciate any help.

js

```
$(document).ready (function() {
  $.getJSON("eur_countries_array.json", function (data) {
    var countries = [];
    for (var obj in data){        
        countries.push({
            title: data[obj].title,  
            flag: data[obj].flag,
            population: data[obj].population,
            avg_annual_growth: data[obj].avg_annual_growth,
            date: data[obj].date
        });
    }
    // call sort function
    countries.sort(compare);

    // read through array
    var listHTML = "";
    for (var i=0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        // for each country add flag and title to list
        listHTML += '<li><a href="#' + countries[i].title + '"><img class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none alt="'+ countries[i].flag + 's flag" src="flags/16/' + countries[i].flag +'.png" >'  + countries[i].title  + '</a></li>';

        // Append new "pages" after "home" page for each country
        var pHTML = '<div data-role="page" id="' + countries[i].flag + '">';
        pHTML += '<div data-role="header"><h1>' + countries[i].title + '</h1><a data-rel="back">Back</a></div>';
        pHTML += '<div role="main" class="ui-content" class="country_details">';
        pHTML += '<div class="center"><img class="flag_display" alt="'+ countries[i].flag + 's flag" src="flags/64/' + countries[i].flag +'.png" ></div></div>';
        pHTML += '<div><p class="center">Population of ' + countries[i].title + ' is ' + countries[i].population + '</p></div>';
        pHTML += '<div><p class="center">Average annual growth: ' + countries[i].avg_annual_growth + '</p></div>';
        pHTML += '<div><p class="center">Statistics correct as of: ' + countries[i].date + '</p></div>';
        pHTML += '</div>';
        console.log(pHTML);
        $("body").append(pHTML);
    }
    // Display countries list
    // call the refresh method to update the visual styling after adding new elements
    $("#countryList").empty().append(listHTML).listview("refresh");
  });
});
```

html

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h2>European Countries</h2>
  </div>
  <div role="main">
    <ul id="countryList" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
  </div>
</div><!-- page -->
```

Comment: Looks like the problem comes from your sorting function? This works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nr2vnjjt/

Comment: Oops! the problem was this line: listHTML += '<li><a href="#' + countries[i].title + '"><img class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none alt="'+ countries[i].flag + 's flag" src="flags/16/' + countries[i].flag +'.png" >'  + countries[i].title  + '</a></li>'; The href needed to come from .flag and not .title as some country names have spaces which won't work for id. Thanks anyway